# Split inside Align raises overfull hbox - need a local solution

Tags: align, warnings, split

When using a `split` environment inside a `align` environment, I get the Overfull hbox warning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\textwidth{.5\textwidth}% force narrow text to get overfull box

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \label{eqn:lv_sde}
        dr &= (z_1 r - z_2rf)dt + dn_r\\
        df &= (z_4 rf - z_3f)dr + dn_f,
    \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

How can I get rid of it with a localised solution? I don't want to change any global setting, and I want a single number/label for both equations.

#### Details

For reference, I am using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-bristol-thesis-template/kzqrfvyxxcdm) template on Overleaf.

Comment: please always provide a full small document, What is the use case here, the outer align is doing nothing useful as there is only one row so no alignment possible.

Comment: That said the fragment you provided produces no warnings when made into a test document, please edit to give an example that shows a warning.

Comment: Why do you embed the `split` environment inside an `align` environment? Why don't you use `equation` instead of `align`?

Comment: I would use `equation` not `align` and `aligned` not `split` (`split` is an impressively complicated macro far far trickier than any of the other alignements but I'd only use it when that complication is needed, and here `aligned` is fine)

Comment: please don't use an external link, edit the example to make an overfull box (you must be using very large fonts or very narrow columns.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can try that. The template is very large and complicated, so I'm unsure which bits I need to extract to make a minimal working example, but I'll give it a go

Comment: ignore the template, code, just before the equation use `\showthe\textwidth\showthe\font` then the log will show you the text with and font size in use and you can adapt the article class excample to use the same \textwidth but you need to use no more than half of the default text width before this example is overfull.

Comment: I'll do it this time:

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I experience no problems if I replace the `align` and `split` environments with `equation` and `aligned` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:lv_sde}
    \begin{aligned}     
        dr &= (z_1 r - z_2rf)\,dt + dn_r\,, \\
        df &= (z_4 rf - z_3f)\,dr + dn_f\,.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this is more natural code than the OP's but even if I add `[a5paper,twocolumn]` to the code in the question it still doesn't give an overfull box, so I wonder just how small the OP's columns are....

Comment: I've tried this solution and initially it wasn't working. Then I pressed enter after `\end{equation}` to leave a blank line between the end of the environment and the text, and this did the job!

Comment: @Euler_Salter a blank line after `equation` will not affect the display of the equation in any way, it just causes the following text to start a paragraph, so typically be indented.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That makes sense. However, I've tried again and if I remove that line, I get the warning, and if I add it back in, the warning disappears.

Comment: @Euler_Salter that suggests that the overfull box is that line of text  not the math, as by adding a para indent you change the linebreaking of the following text. As always, if you had shown an example and shown the message in the log, it would be clearer.

Comment: @Euler_Salter - Do please edit your posting to show the paragraph that follows the two-row equation. Incidentally, have you deactivated hyphenation in your document?